# Tensorflow Custom Piecewise Cost Function

Tags: python, tensorflow

I need to define a custom cost function in tensorflow, which is piecewise in nature, something like this:

```
def f1(a,b):
    pass #Will do Calculation on a and b
def f2(a,b):
    pass #Will do Calculation on a and b

def customCostFunction(calculated,target):
    if(target > 0): #Trivial Criteria
       return f1(calculated,target)
    else:
       return f2(calculated,target)
```

I am aware that [tf.py_func](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.9/api_docs/python/script_ops.html) exists, but I am unsure exactly how to use it in the above case. In essence, for each value in each of the tensors (predicted vs target), I need the predicted and the target values to be passed through a function defined by me, which will return slightly different results depending on the values passed through (I have two strictly different learning cases).

Then the training step would be defined like this:

```
train = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate = LEARNING_RATE).minimize(tf.reduce_sum(customCostFunction(model,targets),0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you have a tensor `calculated_values` which is a `tf.Variable`, and `target_values` which is a `tf.placeholder`. (Both vectors having the same dimension). Instead of wrapping your cost function into a node operation, why don't you simply do:

```
bool_tensor = tf.greater(target, tf.zeros_as(target))
concat_both = tf.concat(1, [calculated_values, target_values])
required_cost_tensor = tf.select(bool_tensor, tf.map_fn(f1, concat_both), tf.map_fn(f2, concat_both))
tf.reduce_sum(required_cost_tensor, 0)
```

You may have to edit your `f1` and `f2` functions a bit to allow for the types you'll get when `concat_both` is unpacked by `map_fn`

I'm just starting out with tensorflow myself, and I've never used the `tf.py_func` before, so this may not be the most optimal solution.

Comment: Yes your assumption are correct. Both same dimension. One is a placeholder, the other is variable.

Comment: So if you can construct a boolean tensor for your trivial condition, use that to select the elements from the `tf.map_fn(f1, concat_both)` and `tf.map_fn(f1, concat_both)`, you should be good to go. It's just a little sub-optimal, because each of your `(calculated, target)` tuples go through both `f1` and `f2`

Comment: Doesn't work. complaining f1 needs two positional arguments but only one provided.

Comment: Can you get `f1` and `f2` to operate on batches of data? Then just call them directly (no `tf.map_fn`) and use the resulting Tensors as the arguments to `tf.select`.